# Ошибка при настройке темы

Tags: php, wordpress, warning, error404

При попытке настроить тему выдает ошибку

> Warning:
>   require_once(/profiles/d/dr/dra/drat***/***.zzz.com.ua/wp-includes/customize/class-wp-customize-background-image-setting.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /profiles/d/dr/dra/drat***/***.zzz.com.ua/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-setting.php
>   on line 948
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/profiles/d/dr/dra/drat***/***.zzz.com.ua/wp-includes/customize/class-wp-customize-background-image-setting.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/php56u/lib/php') in
>   /profiles/d/dr/dra/drat***/***.zzz.com.ua/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-setting.php
>   on line 948

Ошибка на любой установленной теме, сайт только создан на хостинге zzz.com.ua, загружал файлы через filezilla.

Comment: Файл такой в ядре есть. Возможно, хостинг кривой, если на вновь созданном сайте WordPress отсутствует нужный файл.

Comment: @KAGGDesign есть какой то не кривой на котором будет работать?

Comment: Хостингов много, их обсуждение выходим за рамки этого ресурса.